# SVG element gets cut off when resized+moved

Tags: svg

Given the following SVG embedded in a HTML page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <svg style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">
      <svg y="-25">
        <g transform="scale(2 2)">
          <circle cx="25" cy="37.5" r="25" style="fill:black" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

It shows a circle that is cut-off. The cut-off is influenced by the size of the outermost SVG element in both firefox and chrome. Why does this happen? How can I show the whole circle?

In the real use case for this the "circle" is much more complicated and I am trying to allowing zooming/panning for everything and have run into this problem, the above is just a simple recreation of the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put an `svg` inside another `svg` element, its size defaults to the same size at its container, and will not show anything outside of that bounding box unless you set `overflow:visible` on the inner svg element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <svg style="width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid black">
      <svg y="-25" style="overflow:visible">
        <g transform="scale(2 2)">
          <circle cx="25" cy="37.5" r="25" style="fill:black" />
        </g>
      </svg>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The default value of `overflow` for outermost `<svg>` elements is `visible`. The default value of `overflow` for child elements of an SVG (including child `<svg>` elements) is `hidden`.  This behaviour is specified in the SVG specification:

https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#masking-OverflowAndClipProperties

That is why your circle is getting cut off.  If you want the circle to be visible outside of its parent `<svg>` element, you have to set `overflow: visible` on it. Just as @Shelvacu has suggested.